# How to fill the row with two buttons?

Tags: dart, flutter

How to make two buttons expand equally over the entire width of the Navigation Drawer?

---

[image: Actual vs Required]

Comment: I understand that this is your first question in stack overflow, however, to help you with this, you need to provide additional information - like what platform, what layout is used for parent and so on.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The main thing will be

```
        ListTile(
          title: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(child: RaisedButton(onPressed: () {},child: Text("Clear"),color: Colors.black,textColor: Colors.white,)),
              Expanded(child: RaisedButton(onPressed: () {},child: Text("Filter"),color: Colors.black,textColor: Colors.white,)),
            ],
          ),
        )
```

---

[image: Result]

---

*Complete Code*

```
class SO extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: <Widget>[
            DrawerHeader(
              child: Text('Drawer Header'),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Item 1'),
              onTap: () {
                // Update the state of the app
                // ...
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              //contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(<some value here>),//change for side padding
              title: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(child: RaisedButton(onPressed: () {},child: Text("Clear"),color: Colors.black,textColor: Colors.white,)),
                  Expanded(child: RaisedButton(onPressed: () {},child: Text("Filter"),color: Colors.black,textColor: Colors.white,)),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: If you don't want the spacing on the sides then either
1. Remove the `ListTile` surrounding the `Row` or
2. Set the `contentPadding` of `ListTile` as required. which is the preferred way.

Comment: I have 7 buttons in a row. A row can have only 2-3 buttons as per available width of mobile. Kindly suggest me how can I wrap multiple buttons in row automatically? Thank you.

Comment: @Kamlesh use the `Wrap` widget https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z5iw2SeFx2M

Comment: Wrap has alignment attribute but it is not capable to use full of outer width then wrap the all the buttons align center. This is big issue for me. Still searching another solution. Thanks

Comment: Got it solution, Wrap is inline-block type widget. Wrap widgets does wrap the inner children widgets but does not take full of width to adjust them.. If our wish is to align center to all the children widgets of Wrap widget then "alignment: WrapAlignment.center," attribute only will not be sufficient. We will have a add a parent widget called "Align(alignment: Alignment.center, child: Wrap(....." then all the children of Wrap widget will be aligned center. This is just personal experience., sharing to help other users. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap each button with Expanded.

```
Row(
children : <Widget>[
 Expanded(
    child: Button(
            child: Text("Clear")
           )
         ),
Expanded(
    child: Button(
            child: Text("Filter")
           )
         ),
])
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Route route =
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MinionFlare());
                    Navigator.push(context, route);
                  },
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,
                    child: Text("Minion"),
                  ),
                ),
                RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Route route = MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => EmojiRatingBar());
                    Navigator.push(context, route);
                  },
                  child: SizedBox(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,
                      child: Text("Emoji")),
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

Comment: I have 7 buttons in a row. A row can have only 2-3 buttons as per available width of mobile. Kindly suggest me how can I wrap multiple buttons in row automatically? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
Container(
            height: 100,
            child: Row(
              children : <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                  child: RaisedButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          color: Color(0xff0000ff),
                          child: Text("Left Button", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),)
                        )
                      ),
              Expanded(
                  child: RaisedButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          color: Color(0xffd4d4d4),
                          child: Text("Right Button")
                        )
                      ),
              ])
          )
```

Comment: Use Expanded widget in a Row widget as demonstrated above

Comment: I have 7 buttons in a row. A row can have only 2-3 buttons as per available width of mobile. Kindly suggest me how can I wrap multiple buttons in row automatically? Thank you.

Comment: Wrap each Button in a Container and use the screen width to determine the width of each Container. **MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.7** as the width of the Container.

Comment: Thanks dear for your quick reply. Using media query is the last solution. I think there should be an inbuilt widget in Flutter. If you know, kindly share. Thanks dear.